# named range count in worksheet results in zero when it has named ranges

Tags: excel, vba, count, range, named

When I query the worksheet Start in the immediate window for a count of named ranges I get 0, although I have 9 named ranges in the sheet. The immediate window instructions and the 9 named ranges are also shown below. Any idea why? Thank you for your help.

Immediate window instructions.

?worksheets("Start").names.count

0

?Activeworkbook.Names(31).Name (the active workbook query confirms the existence of the named range)

EndTime

?Activeworkbook.Names(31,refersto) (the active workbook query also identifies the address of the named range)

=Start!$N$10

I have 9 named ranges in the worksheet Start shown in the table below with various attributes.

```
RangeName   Worksheet Address Index Merged  Visible

EndTime         Start   $N$10   31  FALSE   TRUE

LastRefreshDate Start   $N$4    43  FALSE   TRUE

LastRefreshed   Start   $N$4    44  FALSE   TRUE

RefreshTime     Start   $N$7    46  FALSE   TRUE

ReportFolder    Start   $B$31   47  FALSE   TRUE

RunDate         Start   $N$8    48  FALSE   TRUE

RunDateTime     Start   $N$8    49  FALSE   TRUE

StartTime       Start   $N$9    53  FALSE   TRUE

Version        Start    $N$28   64  FALSE   TRUE
```

Comment: `Worksheet.Names` refers to worksheet-scoped names. Yours are workbook-scoped (as evidenced by the "workbook" in  `ActiveWorkbook.Names...`

Comment: Well to qualify my previous comment - `Workbook.Names` also includes worksheet-scoped names, so the 2nd sentence is a bit off. In any case, you're still dealing with workbook-scoped names.